# Has a nuclear explosive ever been detonated by another nuclear explosive? That is, a "secondary nuclear explosion"

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

So the question is this: Even though thermonuclear explosives(those with 2++ stages) are complex devices that require symmetrical compression in order to detonate(the fission stage). If, say, a thermonuclear warhead is close enough to the center of a nuclear explosion such that it is well within the fireball radius(<1000 feet away), could the intense gamma rays trigger photofission of the fission primer so that the fission would be rapid enough to be explosive? Thus generating enough radiation pressure to ignite the fusion stage? I read an *anecdote* that this did occur during an underground nuclear test and it boosted the explosive force, but by less than the sum of the combine warhead yields. But if this had actually been tested, I'd be interested to see the documented results.

Comment: Do you have a link to the anecdote?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not. It was mentioned on Quora but with no references. So it's pretty much hearsay. It might still be classified and not publicly available.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a question about history rather than physics.

Comment: [skeptics.se] might be better suited for the question of whether the anecdote occured or not.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this has ever happened, at least not in the West.  There is an excellent and fairly recent (2013) book on nuclear near catastrophes called "Command and Control" by Eric Schlosser (see also [this interview](http://www.npr.org/2014/08/11/339131421/nuclear-command-and-control-a-history-of-false-alarms-and-near-catastrophes)).  The book is very comprehensive (at least as far as US arsenal is concerned) and would have most likely mentioned this incident irrespective of where it happened if this careful author had heard of it at the time of writing.

It is possible that such a thing could have happened since then, or have happened a more secretive society (v.g. North Korea or China) but it seems to me highly unlikely that an accident like this would not have leaked in some serious publication if it had happened in the West.

(Nota: *uncontrolled* nuclear detonations are expected to generically messy and thus much more likely to pose a threat to the public at large, hence also more likely to the subject of an information leak, than *controlled* denotations.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @ZeroTheHero's answer that it so far *has not* happened, I wanted to point out that it's also not the sort of thing that *would* happen.

## The mathematics of chain reactions

So inside a fissile material, there are constant random decays of individual atoms; that's why this thing has a *half-life* in the first place. Each one emits some number of neutrons and gamma rays, some of which find nearby nuclei and cause them to fission. So there is a number, "A given nuclear fission causes $N$ 'immediate child' nuclear fissions to happen," just like a given person has some number of immediate children but they can have their own children and so on. And this number $N$ is what we call a "random variable" -- it depends on where the neutrons happened to be pointed and whether there happened to be a nucleus in their way in that direction, so it might take many values with many different probabilities. The average of this random variable, denoted $\langle N \rangle,$ becomes very important.

See, our world is not very exact, so we can discard the $\langle N \rangle = 1$ case and divide such phenomena into two classes: $\langle N \rangle < 1$ and $\langle N \rangle > 1.$ We call these "negative feedback" and "positive feedback" or "sub-critical" and "super-critical" or "mostly safe" versus "oh my god we're all going to die." The reason is what we call the geometric progression: the total number of reactions that happen as an indirect result of one nuclear decay. Up to generation $g$ of "child" fissions of the one, this will be $$T(g, \langle N\rangle) = \langle N\rangle + \langle N\rangle^2 + \langle N\rangle^3 + \dots + \langle N\rangle^g$$

It turns out that we can analytically sum this up into the formula that after $g$ generations of new fissions this number is $$T(g, \langle N \rangle) = \langle N \rangle \frac{\langle N \rangle^g - 1}{\langle N \rangle - 1}.$$Now if  $\langle N \rangle  < 1$ this thing will actually converge to a constant for large $g$, namely $T(\infty, \langle N \rangle) = 1/((1/\langle N \rangle) - 1)$. So if the average number of fissions created by a new fission is $2/3$ then overall a random fission will create only $1/((3/2) - 1) = 1/(1/2) = 2$ new "descendant" fissions on average, and that includes the ones that they create and so on; if it creates $0.99$ on average then each random fission ultimately causes $99$ more descendant fissions, all told, and things may get very warm but they do not explode. We say that the number of fissions *exponentially decay* as the generation increases. The chains of "this causes that" eventually die out. (Remember that Avogadro's number is getting up towards $10^{24}$ atoms in macroscopic objects, so you have to be *really* close to $1$ in order to get numbers that affect any significant number of fissile atoms.)

But if $\langle N \rangle > 1$ then this thing *grows exponentially* towards infinity. Only some of the chains of "this causes that" die out, and it does not take long to find chains of 100 or 1,000 or 10,000 generations, growing out of control. So these occasional random decays suddenly overwhelm the material, and a large proportion of the fissile material decays nearly at once, as no matter how slow this process goes, most of the "oomph" is a few dozen generations from the last one.

## How we implement that in the physics

Basically, if you put two masses of fissile material together, some of the neutrons which would have flown free out of the one, now hit nuclei in the other and vice versa. So one key feature is having "enough stuff close enough" that causes a chain reaction to occur. This is called a critical mass. In normal fission bombs two halves which are not by themselves above the critical mass are often blasted together by a primary explosive agent. In addition at nuclear power plants we might have gaps which are open in our lump of fissile material, which we insert rods into that block or absorb neutrons that would otherwise fly through the gaps into other nuclei. So those are the two basic ways that we control this, we usually mash material together to increase $\langle N \rangle$ or mash some other stuff into open gaps to decrease $\langle N\rangle.$

Most nuclear power plants actively attempt to control $\langle N \rangle$ to bring it near $1$ without going over for substantial periods of time; the closer you get it the more the reactor core heats up and the more steam you generate, so the more power that you get. There can be active problems if you evaporate all of the water as those water molecules can be absorbers for neutrons, so if the thing goes dry then $\langle N \rangle$ can increase precipitously past 1.

Interesting research has been done on systems which inherently limit themselves by becoming less reactive as they get warmer, see e.g. [this Wikipedia article on LFTRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_fluoride_thorium_reactor).

## Why this all matters to your question

You are interested in what happens when we add additional *sources* of random decay events, but these are highly unlikely to cause substantial fission unless they directly fission a substantial fraction of the starting mass. To actively *cause* a chain reaction requires something more like a positive [temperature coefficient of reactivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature_coefficient#Temperature_coefficient_of_reactivity), just like how those LFTRs are "inherently safe" due to their negative TCoR: the added temperature would then cause the normally "safe" substance to undergo a sort of "meltdown."

It's not out of the question; a nuclear explosion close enough to a nuclear plant could potentially cause reactor meltdown if, say, the fireball evaporated the water in the core or caused these open spaces (where the neutron-absorbing rods normally go) to collapse or so. For that matter the compression wave could potentially set off the primary explosive that knocks the fissile parts together; these are designed to withstand rather large impacts but the compression wave can certainly be an even larger one. But I am saying that it's probably not the gamma rays which are causing the explosion to "go critical"; that "doesn't smell right" as it doesn't increase this propensity for fissions to cause more fissions $\langle N \rangle$.